# Listing the files inside a folder using batch file

Tags: shell, command-line, command, dos

I am using a batch file to view the contents (xml files) of a certain folder.
I need to use a batch file for it.

Found this command on internet and it is working perfectly when I type in the command prompt, but when I type it in and save as a batch file, it doesn't give any out put at all. (Basically not running the content)

```
FOR /R D:\Myfolder  %F in (*.*) do rename %~nF.xml %~nf1.xml
```

There are no restrictions in the folder either.

Comment: The name of the folder is "Myfolder" in this example.Also it contains only xml files. No folders or other stuff in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't have worked from the prompt.

In a batch file, you need to change any `%` for the `metavariable` (`%F` in this case) to `%%`.

Having said that however,  (or, from the prompt, `%F` and `%f`) are two different animals. It's virtually the only situation where batch is case-sensitive. Your command attempts to rename files using their `NAME` only (`~nF`) so if it was to encounter `fred.txt` it would attempt to rename `Fred.xml` to -er, `1.xml` (I think, maybe `%~nf.xml`)

Best to say what you're trying to do. We're reasonably slick at crufting up solutions...

Comment: Thanks Peter. I changed it to as you said like this "FOR /R D:\Myfolder  %%F in (*.xml) do rename %%~nF.xml %%~nF1.xml"  It's working fine.. Many Thanks (y)